# Dart/Angular 2: Pub serve 404 on page reload

Tags: angular, dart, angular2-routing, dart-pub, angular2-dart

There are some similar questions but I did not find any solution for this problem yet.

Lets assume I use

> pub serve --port 13371

in order to start my Angular 2 / Dart application locally. In the base file I have a router configured like this:

```
@RouteConfig(const [
  const Route(
      path: '/home',
      name: 'Home',
      component: HomeComponent,
      useAsDefault: true
  ),
  const Route(
      path: '/about',
      name: 'About',
      component: AboutComponent
  )
])
class AppComponent {}
```

and a template like this:

```
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a [routerLink]="['Home']">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a [routerLink]="['About']">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

In Dartium or another Browser I go to `http://localhost:13371/` which redirects me to `http://localhost:13371/home`. Whenever I press **reload** now I get a **404 error**.

The reason of this is the server configuration. When angular changes the URL it knows where to go and how to rewrite the URL. But for the server `/home` or `/about` does not exist.

However my question is how can I configure `pub`  in order to redirect always to index.html so that I can refresh and get forwarded to subsite then? Is there some configuration to add to pubspec.yaml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either add

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  /* other providers */, 
  provide(LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy),
])
```

or use a proxy like Nginx that supports rewriting. `pub` itself doesn't support it in any way.

See also https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pub_serve_rewrites

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a slash on your path "/". Try this:

```
const userRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

Comment: That doesn't apply to the router used in Dart Angular 2/3.